# Filter column in data frame based on another column values

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
df
Name  score1  score2  
tim   5       man      
poe   10      girl
rob   -3      man
koi   -2      girl
jan   0       girl
```

I wanna filter the column "score1" with values bigger than 0, but only for names that are "man" in score2.
My idea is to use `dplyr`, and do something like

```
df %>% group_by(score2) %>% filter(score1 > 0)
```

is this way correct?
thank you,
regards

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter( score1 > 0 & score2 == "man")
```